# Nails coming through the visible underside of roof sheathing

Tags: roof, roofing, contractors

I have a rental unit that has a large single slope roof. There is exposed roof decking all around the outside of the house. It is an older place and has been shingled and re-shingled previously.

This has just been re-shingled again, and the nails come through the decking all around the house about 3/4". I have carefully looked at this and it is clear to me that no previous nails have come through in this manner, only the current job.

Nails used were "the shortest nails possible," but in future such jobs should I insist that 1" hand nailing be done over such areas? [image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because contract disputes are off-topic

Comment: The way your questions is worded now it will get closed as seeking legal advice.  To keep your question open you should modify it to ask how to install the roofing to avoid this problem.  Leave out the conflict you are having and focus just on the method to re-reroof this area without nails sticking thru.

Comment: As tyson said you will need to re phrase the question - as for legal advice - see an attorney (ask for a free consult) and talk to a different contractor about what they do in this situation (might cost you - or you can ask for an estimate to fix your issue).

Answer (score 4):

This is industry standard to make sure the nails penetrate the decking. If you don't like it box in the area but you will waste your time in court in my opinion.

Comment: Yep. Roofing manufacturers require it for pullout resistance.